# Is there an out of the box function to convert by culture a number?

Tags: t-sql

Is there an out of the box function to convert by culture a number?

- French France is    12 345 678,90
- Spanish Spain is    12.345.678,90
- English US is       12,345,678.90
- French Canadian is  12 345 678,90
- English Canadian is 12 345 678.90
- Indian is          1,23,45,678.90

I have some luck removing all characters and assume that the first character on the right is a decimal separator if it's withing the 3rd character or pad with zero .00.

This does not work if there is more than 3 decimal characters.

Comment: I don't think there's a built in function to detect culture based on a number (or text for that matter) - but it's pretty east to just take the right most non-digit char and treat it like the decimal separator, regardless of how many digits there are after it....

Comment: That was my first algorithm. If you just do that and there is no decimals then your off by x1000.

Comment: If the left-most and right-most separators are different then the right-most _ought_ to be the decimal separator. Otherwise it is the proverbial crapshoot.

Comment: I was hoping that someone knows of a nice sp with all permutations. Maybe i'll have to clean up my sp and share it on GitHub and let it grow overtime. It might catch more scenarios over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the built-in function:

> TRY_PARSE ( string_value AS data_type USING culture )

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql

```
CREATE TABLE db_tbl ( culture VARCHAR(50), string VARCHAR(50), number NUMERIC(18,9) );

INSERT INTO db_tbl VALUES
  ('fr-FR', '12 345 678,90', 12345678.90),
  ('es-ES', '12.345.678,90', 12345678.90),
  ('fr-FR', '12 345 678', 12345678),  
  ('en-US', '12,345,678.90', 12345678.90),
  ('fr-CA', '12 345 678,90', 12345678.90),
  ('en-CA', '12 345 678.90', 12345678.90),
  ('fr-FR', '12 345 678,900', 12345678.90),  
  ('en-US', '12,345,678.900', 12345678.90),
  ('en-US', '12,345,678', 12345678),  
  ('en-US', '345,678', 345678),  
  ('fr-FR', '345,678', 345.678),  
  ('bn-BN', '1,23,45,678.90', 12345678.90)
  ;

 SELECT culture
, TRY_PARSE(string AS MONEY USING culture)            
, number
FROM db_tbl;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/11963f/1

See Microsoft docs, it doesn't support all cultures (i.e. en-CA) but it's works for me otherwise.